# Offscreen Canvas in Web Worker not Updating when Editing Rendering Context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, web-worker, offscreen-canvas

**context**: I am using a mapping library called [openglobus](https://openglobus.org/) to render a 3d planet. Openglobus has a tile layer, where you can give a function that generates tiles, that function can return canvasses. So what I made is a function that generates these canvasses to get rendered as a map layer on that globe. To keep things performant, this function is asynchronous and calls upon a webworker to do the actual tile generation. So the canvas is made in the main thread by the tile generator function. Then the canvas transfers its control to offscreen. next the webworker gets on it with all required parameters. And when the web worker finishes, the canvas is applied to the globe.

Tile generator function looks like this (WM stands for Worker Manager that distributes requests over the multiple workers):

```
export default function BaseLayer(WM) {
  return new layer.CanvasTiles(`cnv`, {
    isBaseLayer: true,
    drawTile: function (material, applyCanvas) {
      const { tileZoom, tileX, tileY } = material.segment;
      const extent = material.segment.getExtentLonLat();
      const res = 700;

      const cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
      cnv.width = res;
      cnv.height = res;

      const offscreen = cnv.transferControlToOffscreen();

      WM.makeBaseTile({
        extent,
        tileX,
        tileY,
        tileZoom,
        res,
        offscreen,
      }).then(_ => applyCanvas(cnv));
    },
  });
}
```

Workers are created when the page loads and are not destroyed. they are reused for every tile and cache data that is used often. Worker code that draws these tiles is structured like this (simplified):

```
self.onmessage = async (e) => {
  const { id, extent, tileX, tileY, tileZoom, res, offscreen } = e.data;

  const cnv = offscreen
  const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");

  // draw fallback background color
  ctx.fillStyle = g.biomeColors[13]; //"#85a478";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, res, res);

  // Fetching data from online resources to draw
  let [biomeRes, waterRes, hillshade] = await Promise.all([...axios get requests]);

  // before water is added, draw the color of the biome (background)
  biomeRes.data.forEach((BIOME) => {
    BIOME.forEach((b) => {
      // custom function to draw geometries onto canvasses
      drawShape(ctx, b, color, "#000000", e.data, false, 0, false);
    });
  });

  // if water is an empty array, there is no water in this tile
  if (waterRes.length) {
    // jiggle is a custom function to add noise to geometries
    const water = jiggle(waterRes, extent, tileZoom, 3, 2);

    water.forEach((p) =>
      drawShape(ctx, p, "#5b99a6", "#2d4d54", e.data, false, g.outline)
    );
    }
  }

  // toggle tile borders on/off
  if (true) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.font = "50px serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(`${tileZoom}`, 10, 60);
  }

  // draw hillshade, but blend by multiply to avoid white background
  // make opacity fade out when it reaches zoom level of 15, start at 10
  const img = await createImageBitmap(await hillshade.blob());
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  ctx.globalAlpha = Math.max(0, 1 - (tileZoom - 10) / 5);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, res, res);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;

  // ctx.commit();
  postMessage({ origin: JSON.stringify([id, tileX, tileY]) });
```

**problem**: When I coded it this way, I had issues with some tiles not loading. Some of them do, but some of them don't. It happens on both Chrome and Firefox so I don't think it is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466243/offscreen-canvas-not-rendering-some-of-the-time?rq=2), or [this existing Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202481) (that bug also is marked as fixed already).

[image: What it shouldnt look like]

The issue seems to be most prevalent on complexer tiles that take longer to generate. But it is all asynchronous so I don't understand why that could be the reason.

I did find a fix however. That's why I don't think this is an issue with the openglobus library, but with the way offscreencanvasses work. By using the [commit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D/commit) function on the OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D at the end of the worker's process, I get a perfectly working example:

[image: What it should look like]

However this commit function is only available for Safari en Firefox browsers, and not for Chrome(ium) based browsers. Does anyone better understand why this happens without the commit function, or how this can be fixed in Chrome? I have been looking for a while already but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the commit function.

Comment: Please show the worker side code. Are you drawing in `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks? Is the worker killed every frame? Also note that [we're in the process of removing `commit()`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/9979) from the standards.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kaiido! I have added a snippet of the worker-side code. The openglobus library does use the requestAnimationFrame callbacks, but that is abstracted away in the library. I do not interact with that directly, nor do I know the ins and outs of how exactly it is implemented. The workers are not killed every frame. They are reused and cache a lot of frequently used data.

Comment: I see, so this code is not using `requestAnimationFrame` from inside the Worker. So when it sends its message back, the browser hasn't updated the placeholder canvas yet. I shared the 2 common ways to deal with that, but I leave you find which is best for your library. (IMO, and I said in my answer, if possible the *best™* would be to pass `ImageBitmap` objects directly to your library.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of a placeholder `<canvas>` to which the controlling `OffscreenCanvas` has been sent to a worker is only updated in the "update the rendering" steps of the Worker. You need to wait for that "update the rendering" happened before being able to access the content on the placeholder `<canvas>`.

The code you shared is not using `requestAnimationFrame` from inside the Worker. So when it sends its message back to the main thread (which I assume causes the Promise to resolve), the browser may not have updated the placeholder canvas yet, and when the library will try to use the placeholder `<canvas>`, it will still be empty.

- Keep using a placeholder `<canvas>` and wait for the next painting frame, e.g. in your Worker you'd execute the drawing in a `requestAnimationFrame()` callback, then notify your main thread through `postMessage()` which should be handled in the next task, after the update has been done.
- Do not use a placeholder `<canvas>` and instead transfer your `OffscreenCanvas` content to [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) objects, with the [`transferToImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/transferToImageBitmap) method which will force a synchronous rendering into the `ImageBitmap`. The best would be to feed your library's code directly with the returned `ImageBitmap`, but if it really needs to use a `<canvas>` element, then you can create an [`ImageBitmapRenderingContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext) from the element (`getContext("bitmaprenderer")` and feed it the `ImageBitmap` (`ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(bmp)`).

---

Also note that [we're in the process of removing `commit()`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/9979) from the standards. It's best to not think of it as a solution at all.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! It does make sense to me and I didn't know you could call a requestAnimationFrame from a Web Worker. I see how that could be a valid solution. The idea of sending an image texture back from the worker is an idea I had tried before (raw pixel data, so not performant at all), but added a lot of overhead. Would that also be the case when sending back an ImageBitmap? Because you do mention in your comment on the question itself that that would be the best™ solution, even over the requestAnimationFrame-route?

Comment: (In Chrome and probably in Safari), Transferring an ImageBitmap is way more performant than dealing with raw pixel data. You just move a pointer to a bitmap that can be reused by the GPU with almost no overhead. You can even transfer it from your Worker to the main thread. I know Firefox still hasn't developped ImageBitmap appropriately but rather ise some CPU baked shenanigans, and thus in some cases it might be slower than other solutions there, but I don't think it applies to this case.

Comment: Sending back the Bitmap also required very little rewriting and works like a charm! Because there is no need for it to happen on the main thread, the worker will now also create its own offscreen canvas. everything behaves like expected on Chrome and there indeed does not seem a noticeable difference between Chrome and Firefox. I cannot find the words to express my gratitude! This issue has been on my radar for too long, thanks!

Comment: One more thing. although it works on Chrome now, there is a lot of lag and the main thread freezes or sometimes even crashes to a black screen during moments where a lot of tiles should finish rendering. The main thread freezes but in the profiler the main thread is practically empty. It appears as if transferring the bitmap using cnv.transferToImageBitmap() and posting that result back to the main thread goes not as smooth. On firefox however, this is not an issue. Do you think this could still be related to this issue? If not, I'd gladly open a new issue.