# Returning ImageBitmaps from a webworker to the main thread creates lag spikes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, offscreen-canvas, imagebitmap

**context**: I am using a mapping library called [openglobus](https://openglobus.org/) to render a 3d planet. Openglobus has a tile layer, where you can give a function that generates tiles, that function can return canvasses. So what I made is a function that generates these canvasses to get rendered as a map layer on that globe. To keep things performant, this function is asynchronous and calls upon a webworker to do the actual tile generation. So the canvas calls the webworker in the main thread by the tile generator function. The webworker than receives the info it needs and makes an image. And when the web worker finishes, a (pointer to the) ImageBitmaps is returned.

Tile generator function looks like this (WM stands for WorkerManager that distributes requests over the multiple workers):

```
export default function ObjectLayer(WM, level) {
  return new layer.CanvasTiles(`cnv`, {
    isBaseLayer: false,
    height: level * 1 + 0.2,
    minZoom: 12,
    opacity: 0.9,
    drawTile: function (material, applyCanvas) {
      const { tileZoom, tileX, tileY } = material.segment;
      const extent = material.segment.getExtentLonLat();
      const res = 600;

      WM.makeObjectTile({
        extent,
        tileX,
        tileY,
        tileZoom,
        res,
        level
      }).then(applyCanvas);
    },
  });
}
```

Workers are created when the page loads and are not destroyed. they are reused for every tile and cache data that is used often. Worker code that draws these tiles is structured like this (simplified):

```
self.onmessage = async (e) => {
  const { id, extent, tileX, tileY, tileZoom, res, level } = e.data;

  // create offscreen canvas with size res x res
  const cnv = new OffscreenCanvas(res, res);
  
  // filter the data to be shown on the tile
  const data = allData.filter((d) => {
    } if (d.geometry.type == "Polygon") {
      return booleanIntersects(d.geometry, tileGeom)
    } else if (d.geometry.type == "LineString") {
      return booleanIntersects(d.geometry, tileGeom)
    }
    return false
  });

  // draw all assets
  if (level == 1) {
    data.forEach((d) => {
      const asset = PlayerAssets[d.type];
      asset.draw(asset, ctx, d, td, level, pixelRes);
    });
  }

  // convert the canvas to an image bitmap and post it back to the main thread with the transferToImageBitmap() method 
  const imgBitmap = cnv.transferToImageBitmap();

  postMessage({ origin: JSON.stringify([id, tileX, tileY, level]), imgBitmap }, [imgBitmap]);
};
```

When the message is posted back, the WorkerManager (WM) makes sure the image data gets back to the original caller of the function. All of this was also part of an [earlier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77814330/offscreen-canvas-in-web-worker-not-updating-when-editing-rendering-context) that went into the best way of returning the image from the worker to the main thread. Converting the canvas to an imageBitmap was the conclusion.

**problem**: This works fine, Images are returned properly and get displayed. But when checking for chrome, there is a lot of lag and the main thread freezes (dropped frames) or sometimes even crashes to a black screen during moments where a lot of tiles should finish rendering. The main thread freezes but in the profiler the main thread is practically empty. It appears as if transferring the bitmap using cnv.transferToImageBitmap() and posting that result back to the main thread goes not as smooth. On Firefox however, this is not an issue.

[image: profiler]

Is there something in the implementation of this that could cause this many dropped frames on Chrome, but not on Firefox?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to reach back to you on your last message. Might be hard for us to debug without the full app though. As a test, could you try to not transfer the ImageBitmaps at all and to `.close()` it from the worker thread directly? Then if it fixes the issue, could you try to send them to the main thread and to `.close()` directly in the `message` handler, and if this does still prevent the issue, then can you try to `.close()` it after the library used it? Could be that your GPU's memory is filled if the lib doesn't close those itself. (but it can also be thousands other things)

Comment: No worries @Kaiido, I already appreciate the quick responses! Thank you for giving me some more options to try out. Closing the bitmap at different points was an interesting tool to figure out where in the process it might happen, but no matter where I put it, the dropped frames did not go away. The only thing that did help however was disabling the cnv.transferToImageBitmap()! That seems to be the code that causes the dropped frames in Chrome.

Comment: Also in the profiler chart, there is a line that nicely corresponds to the timeline where frames are dropped. But I cannot for the life of me figure out what the striped/hashed line chart represents

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark, but could you try to initialize your 2d context with the `willReadFrequently: true` option?

Comment: Setting willReadFrequently to true does make it so that the main thread isn't blocked anymore. however transferToImageBitmap does take 10 seconds for a single execution. I did manage to make a codepen showing the issue: https://codepen.io/program-sam/pen/VwRzPxJ. Although I do think this is pushing close to the limits of hardware, rather than something in software.  But then there is still a big difference in how Chrome vs FireFox handle a case like this (which can also be tested with the codepen)

Comment: Oh, that's a lot of `drawImage` calls. Are these really needed? For instance this exact codepen could be rewritten by filling a single path containing all the arcs on the main`ctx`.

Comment: Those are indeed a lot of drawImage calls. In the simplified codepen it could be optimized for sure, but in my project, these 'stamps' are objects like trees, buildings, fields etc. here is an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgTj3.jpg. I did already choose to generate procedural and static tiles, rather than having all these objects on the actual globe for performance reasons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256655/discussion-between-sam-and-kaiido).